# How to execute ol.extent button from a new button in OpenLayers 3?

Tags: openlayers

I'd like to move the ol.extent button that it shows in div.map to new button in another div.

I have the following code but without success:

```
    <a href="" data-toggle="button" id="buttonSetPosition">Set Position</a>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#buttonSetPosition").on("click", function() {
            $('.ol-zoom-extent').click();
        });
    </script>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In 3.7.0 you can do it that way:

```
var extent = [123,345,567,891];

$('#custom_btn-zoomtoextent').on('click', function () {
        map.getView().fit(extent, map.getSize());
});
```

(in older Versions it's fitExtent)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move the button outside the map div, use the target property of the `ol.control.ZoomToExtent` class, see [api](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.control.ZoomToExtent.html)